# getting error: 'incorrect number of dimensions' when executing a function in R 3.1.2. What does it mean and how to fix it?

Tags: r, data.table

Let me first describe you the function and what I have to process.

Basically theres this folder containing some 300 comma separated value files. Each file has an ID associated with it, as in 200.csv has ID 200 in it and contains some data pertaining to sulphate and nitrate pollutants. What I have to do is calculate the mean of these particles for either one ID or a range of IDs. For example, calculating the mean of sulphate for ID 5 or calculate the same thing for IDs 5:10.

This is my procedure for processing the data but I'm getting a silly error in the end.

1. I have a list vector of these .csv files.
2. A master data frame combining all these files, I used the data.table package for this.
3. Time to describe the function:

   ```
   pollutantmean <- function(spectate,pollutant,id)
                    specdata <- rbindlist(filelist)
                    setkey(specdata, ... = 'ID)     ## because ID needs to be sorted out
                    for(i in id)
                    if(pollutant == 'sulphate'){
                    return(mean(specdata[, 'sulphate'], na.rm = TRUE))
                    }else{
                    if(pollutant == 'nitrate'){
                    return(mean(specdata([, nitrate], na.rm = TRUE))
                    }else{
                    print('NA')}
                    }
                    }
   ```

Now the function is very simply. I defined spectate, i defined the for loop to calculate data for each id. I get no error when function is run. But there is one error that is being the last obstacle.

'Error in "specdata"[, "sulfate"] : incorrect number of dimensions'
When I execute the function. Could someone elaborate?

Comment: Edit: Apologies for the typo. Its 'specdata' and not spectate. Noob auto correction  :x

Comment: There are 2 typos inside this line: `setkey(specdata, ... = 'ID)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the kind of task where the `plyr` function will be really helpful.
More specifically, I think you should use `ldply` and a bespoke function.

`ldply`: as in a list as the input and a dataframe as the output. The list should be the directory contents, and output will be the summary values from each of the csv files.

Your example isn't fully reproducible so the code below is just an example structure:

```
require(plyr)
require(stringr)

files_to_extract <- list.files("dir_with_files", pattern=".csv$")
files_to_extract <- str_sub_replace(files_to_extract, ".csv$", "")

fn <- function(this_file_name){
    file_loc <- paste0(dir_with_files,  "/", this_file_name, ".csv")

    full_data <- read.csv(file_loc)
    out <- data.frame(
        variable_name=this_file_name,
        variable_summary= mean(full_data$variable_to_summarise)
    )
    return(out) 
}

summarised_output <- ldply(files_to_extract, fn)
```

Hope that helps. Probably won't work first time and you might want to add some additional conditions and so on to handle files that don't have the expected contents. Happy to discuss what it's doing but probably best to read [this](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper), as once you understand the approach it makes all kinds of tasks much easier.